# order of execution of js in iframes set by javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to understand the behavior of code execution order in iframes and it seems to be different in FF and chrome. 
The use case is simple: we have two functions in top frame, creation manager and window creation. window creation function finds an iframe and sets its src attribute to
`javascript:top.writeBody(document)'` where writeBody is using document.write to insert the html in the frame. The html inserted on its end contains a script tag with simple log statement. 
the creation manager function is used to trace the order of execution and to uncover the difference in handling the order in FF/IE compared to Chrome:

In FF the execution flow is as this:

```
[20:40:37.893] Entering creation manager
[20:40:37.893] Starting next job
[20:40:37.893] Invoking createWindow
[20:40:37.894] Setting src of frame
[20:40:37.895] Done setting src on frame
[20:40:37.895] Exiting jobs
[20:40:37.953]  >>> executing script in frame
```

While in chrome the same code gives:

```
Entering creation manager 
Starting next job 
Invoking createWindow 
Setting src of frame 
 >>> executing script in frame
Done setting src on frame 
Exiting jobs
```

Basically in chrome the script in the iframe is executed in the stack of the creation manager call while in FF/IE it is executed after the creation manager call is completed.

So my question is: why is this different and is there a way to make Chrome behaves like FF and IE in this scenario. I have a huge legacy code base that is relying on the FF/IE behavior and the use case is not as trivial as the example but much more spaghetti like, so it would really be useful!

Code sample follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test scenario.</title>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>document.write("<iframe id='c1' src='about:blank'></iframe><iframe id='c2'></iframe>");</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the javascript

```
var jobs = [];
var jobn = 0;
var creationManaer = function() {
    console.log('Entering creation manager');
    if (jobs.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    console.log('Starting next job');
    jobs[jobn]();
    console.log('Exiting jobs');
    jobn++;
    if (jobn >= jobs.length) {
        jobs.length = 0;
        jobn = 0;
    }
}

var body = "<script>" +
"console.log(' >>> executing script in frame');" +
"</script>" +
"<body></body>";

var writeBody = function(doc) {
    doc.write(body);
};

var i = 1;
var createWindow = function() {
    var frame = document.getElementById('c' + i);
    i++;
    console.log('Setting src of frame')
    frame.src = 'javascript:top.writeBody(document)';
    console.log('Done setting src on frame');
};

jobs[jobs.length] = function() {
    console.log('Invoking createWindow');
    createWindow();
}
window.onload = function() {
    creationManaer();
};
```

Comment: By the way - it is not caused a difference in how console calls are handled - the reason I need this is because the relevant code is written in such a way it calls top frame function and it relies on the call stack to be completed (unlike in chrome where it has not) which breaks the whole thing.